# jQuery keypress event does not persist after ajax call

Tags: jquery, load, keypress, posts

I'm trying to creat simple comment system for wall posts (like facebook wall)
and I'm using load more button to show 10 more posts from database everytime "show more" button clicked ...
and for every post there is comment textarea, to add comment I'm using the "Enter keypress function" ..

Keypress event works as desired before ajax call.

When user activates the load more posts event, the keypress event no longer functions, I checked page source code, the posts loaded source code not found on the page but this posts appear in browser !!

add comment function :

```
    $(function() {
    $('.comment-form').keypress(function(event) {
        if (((event.keyCode || event.which) == 13) && !event.shiftKey) {
            // My ajax request here
                }
            });
    });
```

load more function :

```
    $(function() {
        //More Button
        $('.more').live("click",function() {
            var ID = $(this).attr("id");
            if(ID) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "{$url}/ajax.php",
                    data: "loadmore="+ ID, 
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html) {
                        $("#loadmore").append(html);
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

HTML :

```
        <div class="message">
        $Message
        </div>
        <div class="commenter">
        <textarea id="$id" class="comment-form" type="text" placeholder="Write comment..." maxlength="1000"></textarea>
        </div>
```

I'm beginner please help :)

Comment: For testing can you use google chrome? If you can put inside of key press handler function 'debugger;' at the beginning in the Developers Tools window. And check does the code is working after loading more results. If function will not work publish what kind of error you are receiving. And we can help you more.

Comment: sorry I dont now how to use debugger :( , but the error shown above appears in all browsers.

Comment: I noticed in the Facebook wall, that the textarea field does not appear to add comments until user click "add comment", if this is the solution please guide me to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code to have keypress event bind for all the future html along with current html in DOM -

```
$('.comment-form').on('keypress', (function(event) {
    if (((event.keyCode || event.which) == 13) && !event.shiftKey) {
        // My ajax request here
    }
}));
```

Comment: thank you, but your code make the same the error above :( , and the brackets in wrong arranging .

Comment: have you tried with jquery live function to bind the keypress event.

Comment: live function works yahoooo :D , big thanks Balachandra.

Answer (score 0):

The html content loaded via ajax won't have the event attached to it, it's new. Attaching the event is not retrospective. You will need to run the function that attaches the events to the new HTML.

Comment: I attached the keypress event for all new calls (loaded posts), this time Enter key frozen and does not work even does not make new lines.